# Pattern cannot start with "?" - facing regex path matching issue in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js, request-headers

In my Next project , in next.config.js I was trying to use [regex path matching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#regex-path-matching) as mentioned in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#regex-path-matching). What I want to do is match every routes except for a particular one so I have added the regex `^(?!.*books).` which doesn't match anything with `books` . But when I try to give it in my next.config.js in the headers section file like this:

```
    async headers() {
            return [
                {
                    source: "/^(?!.*books).*$",
                    headers: [
                        {
                            key: "Content-Security-Policy",
                            value: "base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src 'self';"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "Strict-Transport-Security",
                            value: "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "X-Content-Type-Options",
                            value: "nosniff"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "X-XSS-Protection",
                            value: "1; mode=block"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "X-Frame-Options",
                            value: "deny"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

And when I try to run the app with `npm run dev` , It is throwing the error `Pattern cannot start with "?"`. I don't understand why this is showing like this, because it clearly is a valid regex and I have tested. Why is it not working in the next.config.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for this particular solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15712#issuecomment-666676618

So according to this github thread the regex I had to use was `((?!books).*)`

```
{
                    source: "/((?!books).*)",
                    headers: [
                        {
                            key: "Content-Security-Policy",
    .....
```

This finally worked for me, but I still don't understand why its different in this case, why is its `((?!books).*)` instead of `^(?!.*books).*$` . It would be helpful if someone can explain this.